# C# Finding bound areas in Images

Tags: c#, ocr

I'm working on an OCR program for one of my classes and I'm trying to find circular closed regions in the text to classify characters. Words have already been skeletonized. For example, in this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBO6c.jpg

I'd like to find the location of the circular O or even the half circle in the E.  I've attempted to convert the pixels into an array and then loop through all the white pixels, finding closed paths but this didn't work. I might not have implemented this correctly however. Any other solutions? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Unfortunately I cannot use Tesseract or other OCR programs because I have to develop my own for my college class. I've used the AForge library to do many tasks such as the skeletonization and wanted to use the circle detection or shape detection classes there but these shapes are too obtuse to work with that.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: Have you tried Tesseract? http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to find closed areas is to use flood fill algorithms.  Assuming a pixel at the edge of the image (e.g. 0,0) can't be in a closed in area start from there and flood out.  Then you can eliminate all pixels in that flood.

Work through the other pixels in the image (that aren't part of your set of bounding pixels) and do floods.  These floods are 'enclosed', you could eliminate them if they reach the edge of the image if you want to.  Each flood should take in a reasonable number of pixels so this algorithm eliminates pixels pretty quickly.

In your case I'd suggest you need to set a minimum area (pixel count) to exclude noise.